# Javascript-generated HTML also prints "undefined"

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a menu with artist names and images pulled from the last.fm API. Currently, it generates the list of images and names fine, except it prints "undefined" at the top of the list. I've tried commenting out the part that populates the elements with artist names/images, and just had it generate the elements, but it still prints undefined. I'm totally stumped as to what it's saying is undefined.

First it makes an AJAX call to get the information it needs:

```
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Non-IE browsers
httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 8 and older
httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

httpRequest.open("GET", 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=chart.gettopartists&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026&format=json', true);

httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
var done = 4, ok = 200;
// Parse the JSON into JavaScript immediately on receipt
if (httpRequest.readyState == done && httpRequest.status == ok) {
  artistList = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
```

Then it processes that information and generates HTML that it implements with inner.HTML

```
var artistsAndImage = {};

for (var i=0; i < artistList["artists"]["artist"].length; i++) {
var name = artistList["artists"]["artist"][i]["name"];
artistsAndImage[name] = artistList["artists"]["artist"][i]["image"][0]["#text"];
};
var code;
// Generate HTML for sidebar with artist names and iamges
for (var name in artistsAndImage) {
nameid = name.
      replace(/ /g, "_").
      replace(/&/g, ":amp").
      replace(/\+/g, ":plus");
code += "<element id=\"" + nameid + "\" onclick=\"details(this)\">\n<p style = \"cursor:default\">\n <img src=\"" + artistsAndImage[name] + "\" alt=\"alt\" width = \"50\" height = \"50\">\n" + name + "\n</p> </element>\n";
};
 document.getElementById("sidebar").innerHTML = "<div style = \"padding:20px\">" + code + "</div>";
```

Where's the "undefined" coming from, and how can I fix it? You can see the current incarnation of the page uploaded here: http://test.yukot.corp.he.net/

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is causing this extra "undefined"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381618/what-is-causing-this-extra-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate your `var code;` with an empty string:

```
var code = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I can see three possible causes of the `undefined` showing up, either `artistList["artists"]["artist"][i]["image"][0]["#text"]` doesn't always exist (this line `artistsAndImage[name] = artistList["artists"]["artist"][i]["image"][0]["#text"];`)
After that, you define a variable, `code`, but its value is (automatically) set to `undefined`, you don't initialize it to a string: `var code = '';` should solve that. 
An other explanation is your looping through the object, without checking if the property you're processing is defined on the instance itself:

```
var code = ''; //initialize code to empty string
for (var name in artistsAndImage)
{
    if (artistsAndImage.hasOwnProperty(name))
    {
        code += 'First string';
        //only process those that are instance properties
    }
}
```

To be absolutely sure, you could check for `undefined`, too:

```
var code = '';
for (var name in artistsAndImage)
{
    if (artistsAndImage.hasOwnProperty(name) && artistsAndImage[name] !== undefined)
    {
        //only process those that are instance properties
    }
}
```

Try this in your console:

```
var code;//code is set to undefined
code += 'part of a string';
console.log(code);//logs: undefinedpart of a string
```